# Telling something in a face to face interview which was omitted during a telephonic interview

Tags: interviewing, internship

Recently when I had a telephonic interview, the interviewer appreciated me for my knowledge on myriad technical fields that are indirectly related to the job.

Shortly after, When he asked about android development I didn't mention that I have some prior experience and was open to learn.

However, I think the reason why I didn't tell about my knowledge on android experience is because it is no where related to my education (I learned android all by myself just like many other technologies that I've told him before) and felt it would somehow create an impression that I would be overqualified.

Nevertheless, The interviewer called me for another face-to-face interview. And I would like have some inputs on how do I approach this matter without creating an bad impression.

PS. I am a student and this would probably be my first job to gain experience in practical scenario.

Comment: So what did you tell him when he asked about your knowledge on android?

Comment: As far as I remember. He, started to mention that knowing android would be advantageous.. (and begins explaining how android development would fit into the line of work)...So to be precise I replied "I do not have experience working with android, but I am enthusiastic about learning and implementing if need be"

I also didn't mention it in my CV for that job because it was not mentioned in the Job Description. And saying that I have android experience after he mentioned about usage of android in the project would create a bad impression. It all happened quickly.

Comment: So, you told him originally "I don't have experience with Android but willing to learn". Now, what exactly are you considering saying? Do you want to say "Oh by the way, actually I know Android better than I let on...". If you change your stance, it will be confusing at best, cause concerns at worst.

Comment: Has enough time passed that you could say something like... "You mentioned in the first interview that Android development would be a plus. I've spent X hours looking in to Android development since then and have already developed a few small tools."?

Answer (score 9):

If you think that your knowledge in android lowers your chances of getting the job you can just continue pretending to know nothing about it. But I doubt that this is the case. When the interviewer asks you if you have knowledge in some field, this field is probably important for the position you are applying to. So you probably shouldn't have pretended to know nothing about it.

I probably wouldn't be so offensive to start the upcomming interview with an akward confession that you do have some experience in android as you just remembered. But if the the interviewer asks you again about this matter you could explain to him that you fiddled a little bit with android in your free time. If he asks why you didn't tell him this before in the phone interview, you could explain that you didn't work professionally with android and that you didn't want to appear pretentious. Portray it as false modesty on your side.

Still this part of the interview might get a little akward. But it is most likely in your best interest to make all your skills clear right at the start or else this will lead to akward situations later down the line.

Comment: Good advice. Being honest (even when it is a little awkward) is always the best policy IMO. Whenever I think an interviewer has heard differently what I was trying to communicate, I usually try and address it with, "I want to make sure I am not misrepresenting myself.." and then follow up a better explanation of what I was originally trying to say. In my experience, the interviewer will respect the desire to portray yourself as honestly as possible.

Answer (score 3):

As a student, no one will be expecting a great deal from you, you may have dabbled in a bunch of technologies, but unless you have 'real' experience or certification then it's not really important beyond showing your basic knowledge.

Just mention you have a bit of experience if they ask again, it's not something that will lose you a job.

Answer (score 2):

When you go in for interview, at some point the word "Android" will come up.  You can say, "Yep, like we discussed on the phone, I've not had any formal schooling in it, but I have poked around and experimented with it.  Here's what I've got..." at which point you basically whip out your portfolio!  Show off whatever apps you've made on your phone and offer to give him links to where (if applicable) on android store or github he can look to download it.